# How to get Largest/smallest date from comma separated list

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have a string of dates separated by comma(,)
It's looks like "20180116,20180115,20180126"

I need to get the smallest date and largest date from this string. Using xslt 2.0

XSLT Code is Looks as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="allDates"><xsl:value-of select="20180116,20180115,20180126"/> </xsl:variable>


<xsl:function name="getLicencingWindowStart">
    <xsl:param name="dates" />
    <xsl:variable name="smallestDateSort" select="tokenize(normalize-space($dates),',')" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$smallestDateSort">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```

o/p:

Expected result is:

Smallest: "20180115"

largest: "20180126"

o/p:

```
<App_Data App="VOD" Name="smallestDate" Value=""/>
<App_Data App="VOD" Name="largestdate" Value="20180126"/>
```

Comment: So where is your code and what have you tried already? Also, I don´t see a question here.

Comment: since i'm new to xslt i didn't tried anything

Comment: Question is how to get smallest and largest date from this string? using xslt2.0

Comment: Consult the list of functions of XSLT/XPath 2 if you want to use the language, for instance https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/ is a compact reference and you will find `tokenize` to tokenize your string into a sequence of strings and the `min` and `max` functions.

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="allDates"><xsl:value-of select="20180116,20180115,20180126"/> </xsl:variable>` doesn't create a variable with a string of dates separated by a comma, it generates a document fragment node containing a single text node with a space separated list of your numbers. Either use `<xsl:variable name="allDates" select="'20180116', '20180115', '20180126'"/>` or `<xsl:variable name="allDates" as="xs:string"><xsl:value-of select="20180116,20180115,20180126" separator=","/></xsl:variable>`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>20190101,20190201,2019051,20190401</root>
```

One way to achieve the desired output can be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="tokenize(normalize-space(/root),',')" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$date">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            Smallest: <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            Largest: <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit:**

As per your comment, if you want to use **xslt 2.0** functions (min & max), the same can be achieved as

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="tokenize(normalize-space(/root),',')" />

    Largest: <xsl:sequence select="max($date)"/>
    Smallest: <xsl:sequence select="min($date)"/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer... it's working partially i'm getting only the largest properly and for smallest i'm getting empty

Comment: Can you share optimal source of your implementation and input file?

Comment: i have shared my snippet can you see that

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to do it in **XSLT 1.0**, build a template like the following:

```
<!-- template: (recursive) find the smallest or largest value in a list of comma-separated values -->
<xsl:template name="findincsv">
    <xsl:param name="csv"/>
    <xsl:param name="which" select="'largest'"/> <!-- smallest or largest (default) -->

    <!-- first value in csv -->
    <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($csv,',')"/> 

    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- if this is the only value: return this one  -->    
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($csv,','))">
            <xsl:value-of select="$csv"/>
        </xsl:when>

        <!-- if this is not the only value: compare the first with the result of this template entering the rest -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- find the wanted value of everything after the first -->
            <xsl:variable name="findinrest">
                <xsl:call-template name="findincsv">
                    <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="substring-after($csv,',')" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="which" select="$which"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>

            <!-- compare to the first -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="($which = 'largest' and $first &gt; $findinrest)
                                or ($which = 'smallest' and $first &lt; $findinrest)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$findinrest"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Then call the template as follows:

```
<xsl:call-template name="findincsv">
    <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="$csv" />
    <xsl:with-param name="which" select="'largest'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

NOTE: the template only works for 'clean' CSVs, with no 'loose' commas at the start or end.
Example how to remove an end comma:

```
<xsl:with-param name="csv" select="substring($csv,1,(string-length($csv) - 1))" />
```